# What is the correct possessive form of "One of the guys"?

Tags: possessives, collective-nouns

Which one should it be?

1. One of the guys'
2. One of the guy's

**EDIT:**

Never mind, I think I answered my own question. I realized it would probably be related to the object being possessed. E.g.:

1. "One of the guys' swords"

   - means "There are multiple guys. **They own multiple swords**. I am referring to one of those swords."
2. "One of the guy's swords"

   - means "There are multiple guys. **One of them owns multiple swords**. I am referring to one of those swords."

Comment: If you answered your own question, feel free to put it in an answer and accept it (you also get a badge for doing that). That way, if anyone else sees this question, they'll also see that it has an accepted answer.

Comment: Although your meaning for 2 isn't quite right.  There need only be one guy with multiple swords: "I met a guy who collected swords.  One of the guy's swords was a made by a Spanish swordsmith in the 1500s."

Comment: @Jim Oh, hm that is true. I think my second example is actually closer to your meaning. So, if we use parentheses to denote precedence, the sentence then goes: "One of (the guy's swords)".

Comment: So how would I represent the meaning I had in example 2? "One of the guys's swords"? Or is my second example correct, and the meaning is ambiguous?

Comment: I would put it this way: **2.** "One of the guy's swords" means "There is one particular guy that I'm focusing on. He owns multiple swords. I am referring to one of those swords."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One of the guys* is *one guy among a group of the guys*. Adding an apostrophe forms the possessive plural ***guys'***:

> *One of the **guys'** swords*

The word *guys'* is **possessive plural**, and the meaning of the sentence is ambiguous, depending on whether *one* modifies *swords* or *guys*:

> ***One sword*** from a group of swords belonging to the guys.
>
> Or
>
> *The swords belonging to **one of the guys**.*

In *one of the guy's swords*, the word *guy's* is possessive singular, and the meaning is straightforward: *One sword belonging to the guy*.